# Is it correct to say: the cat and the mouse are puppets played by Bobby.?

Tags: verbs, american-english, verb-agreement, sequence-of-tenses

I don't know if this is correct because "are" is present tense and "played" is past tense.

Comment: There is no issue with mixing tenses in certain constructs: *In the future, I will have already been married—even though I'm only engaged now.* I'm actually more curious to know if a puppet can be *played*. That doesn't sound right to me. I'd rather use *controlled*.

Comment: Bob, are you suggesting that the cat and the mouse were only puppets in the past, and have now ceased to be puppets?

Answer (score 0):

your sentence is grammatically correct if you're reporting about the puppet show. 
When people report about events, especially the ones that may still be ongoing, using the present tense to describe characters is acceptable.

Look at this [Guardian report](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2018/aug/31/a-star-is-born-review-lady-gaga-bradley-cooper) of "A Star is Born" for reference.

"Puppets played by Bobby" is a definitive so that by itself is correct too.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This sentence grammatically correct.

It is similar to:

```
Football and cricket are the two games played by Steve
```

Answer (score -1):

*Played* is not a past tense here, it's a past participle used as an adjective. They are puppets [which are being] played.